# Importing a constants file in go

Tags: go, import, go-cobra

I have this package structure in my go module, and I am adding commands using cobra-cli:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── cmd
│   ├── constants.go
│   ├── root.go
│   └── tools
│       └── tools.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

In `tools.go`, I want to import `constants.go` which I want to define for globally used constants across all files in my module, and is simple go file:

```
package cmd

const (
    FOO = "https://a.b.c"
    BAR = "https://p.q.r"
)
```

How do I import this? Also is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Import the package containing constants.go as "modulename/cmd"  where *modulename* is replaced with the name of the module in go.mod.  Reference the constants as cmd.FOO and cmd.BAR.

Comment: I had tried that, it gives me the error `import cycle not allowed`

Comment: Probably `tools` imports `cmd` and vice versa. That is not allowed and it is often a mark of bad design, which is true in this case: global place for constants is the evil idea, keep constants where they are used

Comment: You are right, that was the case. There are some constants which will be heavily used across all commands that I am adding, meaning they are truly global. What is a good way to structure this? I don't want to define these in multiple places.

Comment: Break the cycle by moving the constants to a new package.

Comment: `I had tried that, it gives me the error import cycle not allowed` because `constants.go ` and `tools ` is the same package  ,
When your import, you import all of into `cmd` package

Answer (score 0):

`import cycle not allowed` when you used `constant.go` inside `tools.go` and used `tools.go` inside `constant.go`, and create a cycle call each other,   please check you code
`import cycle not allowed` when you used `constant.go` inside `tools.go` and used `tools.go` inside `constant.go`, and create a cycle call each other,   please check you code